# Changing size of a UniformGrid with a user control

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

My main window consists of a "control panel" on the left and a UniformGrid on the right. The size of the UniformGrid (rows and columns) are set by default to a 10x10 grid. In the control panel I have a user control that includes a Slider from 10 (minimum) to 50 (maximum), as well as a Button called "Change Grid". Clicking "Change Grid" should take the current value of the slider and set it to the size of the UniformGrid on the main window.

I know how to do this if I weren't using a user control - the click handler would just set the grid's row/columns to the of the slider - but I'm new to user controls and wpf in general, so not quite sure how to get the same results?

Comment: Show how you would do it *not in a `UserControl`* and we'll show you the difference(s)... it's probably done in a similar way.